# How to display remotebuild server values for cordova+iOS on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2015

I'm following the cordova docs here...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn878133.aspx. Installed remotebuild successfully, but on first run it crapped out, I'm guessing because brew was already installed as it hiccuped at that step. Anyway, I had to perform some of the brew package installations myself, and remotebuild is now working ( I can start the server and run remotebuild test --server http://localhost and it goes to work ) but I have no idea how to retrieve the pin I need to add to the VS2015 TAC configuration. The docs say I should be provided this pin on first run, but I never got em. Where can I retrieve the PIN? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear about your trouble. If you run:

remotebuild generateClientCert

it should give you the pin number you'll need for Visual Studio.

The pin is generated when remotebuild is run for the first time, but if you miss it or have to generate a new one, the generateClientCert option will do that for you. Here is the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551.aspx#IosPin

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. This is the result :

    $ remotebuild --generateClientCert
    remotebuild
    Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    1.0.1

    Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to     configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
    Build Retention initialized with <taco remote builds dir>, maxBuildsToKeep 20
Initialized BuildManager with baseBuildDir <>; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 7854
Remote build server listening on [https] port 3000

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551.aspx#IosPin Note - there is no '--' just "remotebuild generateClientCert"

Comment: Thank you! let me give it a shot